# Impossible to modify or add information after conversion of slapd.conf to cn=config with fresh install of OpenLdap

Tags: debian, ldap, openldap, access-control-list

I start with a fresh installation of openldap 2.4.28 on debian.
They are some problem with the debian package, and with gnuTLS, so i compile a version with opennSSL library.

It's hard to understand with the official documentation how to start a from scratch installation with the new cn=config administration of openLDAP. So, i make a conversion from slapd.conf to cn=config on the first launch of openLDAP with this commands :

```
/usr/local/libexec/slapd -u openldap -g openldap -f slapd.conf.seb -F /usr/local/etc/openldap/slapd.d/ -d -1
```

My slapd.conf.seb equal :

```
include         /usr/local/etc/openldap/schema/cosine.schema
include         /usr/local/etc/openldap/schema/nis.schema
include         /usr/local/etc/openldap/schema/inetorgperson.schema
include         /usr/local/etc/openldap/schema/openldap.schema
include         /usr/local/etc/openldap/schema/misc.schema
include         /usr/local/etc/openldap/schema/ppolicy.schema
include         /usr/local/etc/openldap/schema/gosa/samba3.schema
include         /usr/local/etc/openldap/schema/gosa/trust.schema
include         /usr/local/etc/openldap/schema/gosa/gofax.schema
include         /usr/local/etc/openldap/schema/gosa/gofon.schema
include         /usr/local/etc/openldap/schema/gosa/gosystem.schema
include         /usr/local/etc/openldap/schema/gosa/goto-mime.schema
include         /usr/local/etc/openldap/schema/gosa/goto.schema
include         /usr/local/etc/openldap/schema/gosa/goserver.schema
include         /usr/local/etc/openldap/schema/gosa/gosa-samba3.schema
include         /usr/local/etc/openldap/schema/gosa/openssh-lpk.schema
include         /usr/local/etc/openldap/schema/gosa/dnszone.schema
include         /usr/local/etc/openldap/schema/gosa/nagios.schema
include         /usr/local/etc/openldap/schema/gosa/dhcp.schema
include         /usr/local/etc/openldap/schema/gosa/sudo.schema

pidfile         /usr/local/var/run/slapd.pid
argsfile        /usr/local/var/run/slapd.args

database        bdb
suffix          "dc=parisgeo,dc=cnrs,dc=fr"
rootdn          "cn=admin,cn=config,dc=parisgeo,dc=cnrs,dc=fr"
rootpw  {SSHA} secret
directory       /srv/openldap-data
index   objectClass     eq
```

I have no problem with this simple conversion, but after that, it's impossible to import data with this command ldapadd or ldapmodify.

I don't understand the default right for read/write for openLDAP, i try with ldapmodify, with bind and password, and i have the same problem :

```
root@xxxx:/usr/local/etc/openldap# ldapadd -x -D "cn=admin,cn=config,dc=parisgeo,dc=cnrs,dc=fr" -W -f sauvegarde.ldif 
Enter LDAP Password: xxx
adding new entry "cn=admin,dc=parisgeo,dc=cnrs,dc=fr"
ldap_add: Constraint violation (19)
    additional info: structuralObjectClass: no user modification allowed
```

I try to modify the right for cn=config with this sample :

```
dn: olcDatabase={-1}frontend,cn=config
changetype: modify
delete: olcAccess

dn: olcDatabase={0}config,cn=config
changetype: modify
add: olcRootDN
olcRootDN: cn=admin,cn=config

dn: olcDatabase={0}config,cn=config
changetype: modify
add: olcRootPW
olcRootPW: {SSHA} secret

dn: olcDatabase={0}config,cn=config
changetype: modify
delete: olcAccess

ldapadd -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f slapd.modify.root.ldif
```

Same problem, i have no right todo that, with or without option the password entry -W or bind option -D "cn=config,cn=admin,dc=parisgeo,dc=cnrs,dc=fr"

```
root@xxxx:/usr/local/etc/openldap# ldapadd -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f slapd.modify.root.ldif 

SASL/EXTERNAL authentication started
SASL username: gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth
SASL SSF: 0
modifying entry "olcDatabase={-1}frontend,cn=config"
ldap_modify: Insufficient access (50)

root@xxxx:/usr/local/etc/openldap# ldapadd -x -W -H ldapi:/// -f slapd.modify.root.ldif Enter LDAP Password: 
ldap_bind: Invalid credentials (49)

root@xxxxx:/usr/local/etc/openldap# ldapadd -D "cn=config,cn=admin,dc=parisgeo,dc=cnrs,dc=fr" -W -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f slapd.modify.root.ldif 
Enter LDAP Password: 
SASL/EXTERNAL authentication started
SASL username: gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth
SASL SSF: 0
modifying entry "olcDatabase={-1}frontend,cn=config"
ldap_modify: Insufficient access (50)
```

Do you have an idea of the solution for this from scratch installation ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I understand my mistake,
we need to add this three line to slapd.conf before conversion :

```
database config
rootdn "cn=admin,cn=config"
rootpw {SSHA} secret
```

After conversion, we can test this :

```
ldapwhoami -x -D cn=config -W
```